# how do I use discover to update kubuntu 18.04 to 22.04?

Tags: upgrade, kubuntu, 22.04

all
I have tried to update kubu 18.04 to 22.04 using to command prompt but it doesn't complete.
I would like to use Discover to do the upgrade.
I open discover and search for 22.04 and it lists 2 items only. The 2 listed are quadrix and core 22. Core22 has a description stating it's for runtime environment based on ubuntu 22.04.
I'm stuck. Please help.
Thanx!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I skip over releases when upgrading?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34430/can-i-skip-over-releases-when-upgrading)

Comment: [Ubuntu's release-upgrader tool](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader) can *release-upgrade* a 18.04 system to 20.04, or it could in the past upgrade a 18.04 system to 18.10; but it cannot upgrade to later releases than that.  You need to *release-upgrade* to 20.04, then after reboot & whilst using 20.04 you'll be able to *release-upgrade* to 22.04 **after** 22.04.1 as been released; though it can be *forced* now; but you cannot go there directly.

Comment: Ubuntu Core 22 is an OS; and a very different system to 18.04, 20.04 or 22.04.  You're talking about a *snap* package (core22) which allows your 18.04 system to run *snap* packages that were compiled on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS systems; it'll be automatically installed when needed; but it's not what I believe you think it is.